# How to corectly clear space for "No space left on device" for /boot

Tags: 16.04, apt, kernel, dpkg

The production server I'm using has a **/boot** partition of **400MB**.
And every once in a while if I want to install something from repositories, it tells me that it cannot do that because there is **No space left on device**

I cannot change the server configuration, because I'm not the owner.

I have seen some tutorials ([like this one](http://wisercoder.com/ubuntu-apt-get-f-fails-no-space-left-on-device-apt-get-autoremove-doesnt-work/)) on how to delete the old kernel packages.
However, they all seem sketchy. I don't want to endup having a non-bootable system.

`uname -r` shows me:

> 4.15.0-30-generic

and
`dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'` shows me:

> linux-headers-4.13.0-36 linux-headers-4.13.0-36-generic
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-39 linux-headers-4.13.0-39-generic
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-41 linux-headers-4.13.0-41-generic
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-43 linux-headers-4.13.0-43-generic
>   linux-headers-4.13.0-45 linux-headers-4.13.0-45-generic
>   linux-headers-4.15.0-24 linux-headers-4.15.0-24-generic
>   linux-headers-4.15.0-29 linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic
>   linux-headers-4.15.0-65 linux-headers-4.15.0-65-generic
>   linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic
>   linux-image-4.13.0-39-generic linux-image-4.13.0-41-generic
>   linux-image-4.13.0-43-generic linux-image-4.13.0-45-generic
>   linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.13.0-39-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.13.0-41-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.13.0-43-generic
>   linux-image-extra-4.13.0-45-generic linux-libc-dev:amd64
>   linux-modules-4.15.0-24-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-29-generic

**What is the best way to delete old kernel packages to free up /boot space?**

**Later edit:**

- Any `apt-get` will NOT work. It will report the same error

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` ?

Comment: Most software installed from repositories goes in / and not /boot (unless you're loading additional kernels, grub-legacy etc).  Are you running short of space in / as well?

Comment: @guiverc only `/boot` has no space. ubuntu does fill up the `/boot` every ~3 months with kernels.

Comment: @MadMike I'm unable to run any apt or apt-get commands successfully. It's definitely not a duplicate question. Check my edit.

Comment: A properly setup system should have only the current & prior two kernels, however this can be overridden if holds were placed so more are kept.   Check you or another admin hasn't put holds (`apt-mark showhold`) so old kernels aren't removed; or check changes to your setup.  The best tool is `sudo apt autoremove` from comment 1 but it cannot override holds.

Comment: @guiverc the `apt-mark showhold` shows nothing. the server is from Hetzner and this is their default setup.

Comment: 4.13 kernels are from 17.10  (or 16.04 with HWE) so it's been left un-maintained a long time... and this is the problem.  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels  (the duplicate link is correct in my opinion unless left too late which I think is your problem; the Ubuntu wiki provided does have solutions for that)